# How can my app (an iframe loaded by salesforce) confirm that the user is logged in to salesforce?

Tags: oauth, salesforce, apex-code

We're building a salesforce app, and I need to auth against a user's SF user (so they don't have to log in to SF, then *also* log into our system).

So I from our app, I want to bounce off of SF and:
1) confirm that the user is logged in to salesforce.
2) get (or confirm, if I provide it) some kind of tenant id, so I can confirm that they are logged in to the tenant they are self-reporting to me.

Does SF have docs on this flow somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe i'm getting it wrong but can you explain. If you building "a salesforce app" The user already loged in when he uses it. If it's external Webapp orr mobile app you might find oAuth useful more details here https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_authenticate.htm

Comment: it's a salesforce app that uses an iframe to wrap content from our server. So the user is logged in to salesforce, but from our server's perspective it's just a page being loaded in an iframe. We need to do our own confirmation that they are logged in.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh i got it now i missed the iframe in the title. We had something similar in one of our projects i'll look it up tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

When you put your iframe in Salesforce you can include the current SessionId and ServerURL in the query string parameters.

You can then use the PartnerAPI with these credentials to call back to Salesforce and verify the users details.

There are some very basic details on doing this in [Implementing Salesforce Integrations on Force.com](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_guidelines_yourtools.htm)